# How is this second order derivative with respect to a vector a matrix?

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, vectors, vector-analysis

I have the following equation and I am wondering how it is a matrix?

[image]

As you can see, **$\Theta$** is a vector, as is **u**. I know that the second order derivative of a vector should be a matrix but I am struggling to see why from this equation.

The bottom half when evaluated gives me a vector as does **u** **uT**. So isnt everything just a vector in this equation.

Apologies, I am sure I am being very stupid.

Comment: For matrix product, order matters: $\mathbf v^T \mathbf u$ is scalar, $\mathbf v \mathbf u^T$ is a matrix.

Comment: Thanks. Are you taking the dot product here?

Comment: I am talking about matrix multiplication. Dot product of vectors $\mathbf u\cdot\mathbf v = \mathbf u^T\mathbf v$. In case of vector operation, the other one is called [outer or exterior product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) $\mathbf u\otimes \mathbf v=\mathbf u \mathbf v^T$

Answer (score 2):

Notice that
$$uu^T = \left[\begin{array}{c}u_1\\ u_2 \\ \vdots \\ u_n\end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{cccc} u_1 & u_2 & u_3 & u_4 \end{array}\right] = \begin{bmatrix} u_1u_1 & u_1u_2 & \cdots & u_1u_n\\
u_2u_1 & \ddots & \cdots & u_2u_n\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots\\
u_nu_1 & u_nu_2 & \cdots & u_nu_n\end{bmatrix}$$
is a matrix, so the righthand side of your equation is indeed a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Your $u_t^{(ij)}$ is a vector, so $u_t^{(ij)}u_t^{(ij)^T}$. Denoting this matrix as $U_{ij} = u_t^{(ij)}u_t^{(ij)^T}$ and the scalars as 
\begin{equation}
 \alpha_{ij} = \frac{e^{-\theta_t^T u_t^{(ij)} +b}}{(1+e^{-\theta_t^T u_t^{(ij)} +b})^2}
\end{equation}
You will get $- \sum_{ij} \alpha_{ij} U_{ij} - \lambda I$